# Animate UITextView Text Insertion/entry

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, uitextview

I want the UiTextView text to enter by sliding from right (animation). There are multiple lines in the UITextView, I only want the last line to slide left and the next text to enter from right. For Example.

```
If I have following text on screen on last line 
        345   and user enters 7
       345  7 this should slide to left with animation
       3457   and then 7 should slide there too
```

[image]

I have tried overriding drawrect method and performed animation on the layer, but it moves/slides all of the lines in the UITextView to left and I only need the last line to slide smoothly. Now, the number just appears from no where.

Is there any easy way to do this? I have tried many tricks like taking snapshot of the last line and adding it on the view as image and sliding it, but it doesn't look that good. If I could get hold of drawrect's code, I can make changes to it to suit my needs.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: when do you want to achieve this  animation?

Comment: Whenever entering a new text or text being changed. Please check one example that I provided. Let me post an image too.

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible with only UITextField, there is trick like you have one UITextField where 345 is showing and for next character 7 you have another text field and when user entered you can animate text field for that you have to get the location of XY and there you can hide the UITextField and add the data to non editable filed

Comment: Thanks. This is a UITextView, and I have tried this technique and I am currently using a part of this technique (UITextField) to slide the digit "7" (in my above example). However, its a calculator and user can enter the numbers very fast and I am not getting the smooth flow as I need. I was looking for a way to make changes on CoreText framework level, so that the animation and whole process is smooth and fast.

Comment: Well you can try this but I think using only one bound of a textfield its animation is not possible I hope some one could help you to get th at

Comment: Hope so, Thanks. I was thinking of using a UIScrollView with multiple UiTextFields in it, that will solve the issue but there will be a lot of work that needs to be done, especially replicating behavior of UITextView (such as font size change, moving text on above lines once a line is full, etc).

Comment: Good luck, look here i guess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135796/animate-text-from-right-to-left-in-uitextfield